# How to get disk space low alert?

Tags: shell-script, disk-usage

Our webserver hosted in pair.com uses now over 100% of allowed disk space which is 20GB.

I try to create cron script which emails to 2 email addresses when used disk space is 95% full.

I have this script but i can't figure out whats wrong:

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in "$(du -s /usr/home/ourshortnameinpair)"
do
spc=$(echo $a|cut -d" " -f1)
if [ $spc -gt 1000 ]
then
echo "alert on $1, the space is $spc"|mail ouremailaddresshere -s "Alert space"
fi
done
```

In my.pair.com ACC i have created cron job with correct path: $HOME/disk-usage-alert.sh and did sudo chmod u+x disk-usage-alert.sh and uploaded script to right folder /usr/home/ourshortnameinpair

https://www.pair.com/support/kb/configuring-cron/#a-note-on-cron-job-commands

Comment: The shebang line should just read `#!/bin/bash`. You might also consider indenting your loops and conditionals and check [this](https://www.shellcheck.net/) out.

Answer (score 2):

Please, use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) before posting your scripts here.

```bash
Line 3:
for a in "$(du -s /usr/home/ourshortnameinpair)"
         ^-- SC2066: Since you double quoted this, it will not word split, and the loop will only run once.
 
Line 5:
spc=$(echo $a|cut -d" " -f1)
           ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

I do not have any further comments at this point, so I advise on correcting those main issues, and see if it works or not.